# Is it possible to install Wordpress MU on a subdomain?

Tags: multisite, installation

Times ago I developed a MultiSite Wordpress installation, and now I want to move it from the main root folder to a subdirectory.

Is it possible run an MU version of Wordpress in a subfolder directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes is possible. The only thing is that you will have "two sets" of permalinks:

- example.com/2015/07/27
- example.com/new-website/2015/07/27

[Here is a codex article](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration#SubFolder_installs_and_Permalinks) that explains that.

**Edit 1**: [Here is a more detailed article](https://journalxtra.com/wordpress/how-to-force-multi-site-to-use-subdirectories/) on the topic with it's pros/cons and potential issues.